# PHP Check if actual class is implementing interface

Tags: php, class, inheritance, interface

On an existing project I'm working on, we have the following situation:

```
interface A { }

class B implements A { }

class C extends B { }

class D extends B implements A { }

$B = new B();
$C = new C();
$D = new D();
```

What is the proper way to figure out if the actual class implements the interface *A* and not only the parent class? The check should return **true** for $B and $D and **false** for $C. Normally you would do

```
if( $C instanceof A ) { //do the work }
```

but in our situation this will return true which shouldn't.

An approach can be to parse the file and test if the class really implements A with the [token_get_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php) function. But before doing that, I want to ask if there are more elegant solutions.

I know it sounds weird, but the situation is as it is and the class hierarchy can't be changed. Any insights would be helpful.

Comment: if B implements A, wouldn't all class extending B automatically implements A too ?

Comment: Yes, but I need only classes which actually have the implements A statement. The hierarchy is given because it is an old legacy system.

Comment: `but I need only classes which actually have the implements A statement` can you explain this without going to deeply in explanation ?

Comment: The real world scenario is that I have a list of form fields. One of them is a List form field. Many other form fields do extend from that list field. But I want only the specific ones which do implement A as they make sense in the context I'm using them.

Answer (score 0):

found this solution:

```
function implementsInterface($class, string $interface) : bool
{
    $result = $class instanceof $interface;
    if ($result) {
        return true;
    }
    foreach (class_parents($class) as $subClass) {
        if ($result) {
            break;
        }
        $result = implementsInterface($subClass, $interface);
    } 
    return $result;
}
```